# Identifying Linux distribution from screenshot

Tags: linux, bash, shell, apache-httpd

A friend is asking me to help him out with this old linux box that he has which i believe it like over 15 years old.

He only sent me this screenshot so I don't know much about it yet until i meet with him later in the week.

Does anybody know what distro this might be running?

The shell is The GNU Bourne-Again Shell (bash)?

I'm pretty good with ubuntu and some of the newer linux distros so he asked me to help me retrieve a DB dump and locate the files in the root drectory which i'm assuming this is running apache becuase it's old. I know nginx is highly preferred over apache now a days.

```
mysqldump -u [username] –p[password] [database_name] > [dump_file.sql
```

By default, the Apache web root or Document root folder location is at `/var/www/html`.

[image]

Comment: out of `uname -a`?

Comment: I won't have access to it until Friday. Just wanted to see if anybody could make anything of it to give me a head start. @jesse_b

Comment: The only useful information in there is the version of the bash shell installed there which can give us a rough idea of the era that system is from (circa 2008).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If I'm not mistaken it also indicates that the system is some flavor of GNU/linux.  On macos it would be something like (x86_64-apple-darwin...)  But I guess OP already suspected some flavor of linux

Comment: @jesse_b the OP already said it was a Linux box

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah I know.  They also tried running switch commands on it so who knows.

Comment: `bash` is built for system type `i486-pc-linux-gnu`, so it's a 32-bit Linux on x86 hardware. It's not even optimized for the original Pentium CPU, so it's pretty old/low-spec. With `ls /etc/*release* /etc/*version*` you might find a file that identifies the name and version of the Linux distribution... if the login-time message won't immediately provide that information, that is.

Comment: Is the mysql dump command the standard one like now a days and will the root directory be in /var/www/html?

Comment: That would be mysqldump. The global or per virtual host documentroot directory, if any will be as specified in the apache conf which will likely be some apache2.conf or httpd.conf somewhere in /etc (which itself will likely include other conf files).

Comment: My tip: Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy Heron)

Answer (score 3):

> Does anybody know what distro this might be running?

You can try these commands until one gives you a meaningful answer:

```
cat /etc/debian_version 
cat /etc/fedora-release 
cat /etc/redhat-release 
cat /etc/lsb-release
lsb_release -a
cat /etc/os-release
cat /etc/issue
```

This command won't tell you the distro name, but the kernel version and other useful info:

```
uname -a
```

> The shell is The GNU Bourne-Again Shell (bash)?

Yes, according to your screenshot the shell is Bash 3.2, so the system dates back from  2006-2008.